# Azure relay on iotedge

Tags: azure, azure-iot-edge, azure-relay

Need to deploy an IotEdgehub deployment on a company intranet (For security reasons).

Does azure relay work for the scenario where the server(intranet) is connected to a server with access to the intranet and internet? Or would it be better make use of port forwarding scheme?

Comment: to clarify: Do you want to install IoT Edge on a device, that will not have any outbound connectivity to Azure IoT Hub?

Comment: I have found what I want to do by configuring an IoT Edge device to act as a transparent gateway.